# what is the date after 30days from current date using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I find the date 30 days after the current day? here 30 is the fixed value. how can i pass the dynamic value to this function..

```
days = document.getElementById('day').value;
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + days);
```

it is not working..it gives wrong answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access the time in Javascript using the Date class. Try this:

```
var time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate()+30);
alert(time);
```

**EDIT** Just added a [test jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jT4dg/) in case somebody wants to test it.

Sorry I forgot the adding!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+30);
alert(d)
```

Tested on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we4DF/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var thirty_days_from_now = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 30*24*60*60*1000)
```

Comment: I like this as it's a one liner

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);
```

Comment: here 30 is the fixed value. how can i pass the dynamic value to this function.. days = document.getElementById('day').value; var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + days); it is not working..it gives wrong answer

Comment: Jeny, try a parseInt on days: parseInt(days)